# Is there a way to do the same code if either a mouse button or key is pressed without repeating the code?

Tags: python, pygame, event-handling

I want to create a hint button that works by either clicking on the button or clicking the 'h' key. Is there an easier way to do this without having to repeat the hint button's code?

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit()
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==pygame.K_h:
            code for hint button
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if mouse_x and mouse_y are over hint button:
            code for hint button
```

But I have quite a bit of code under the section "code for hint button" so I would prefer to not have to repeat it twice. Is there a way to bypass this repetition?

I would really appreciate help. Thank you!

Comment: Write a function that contains "code for hint button" and call the function in either case. [clean code](https://www.amazon.de/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882/ref=sr_1_1?adgrpid=72756366884&dchild=1&gclid=CjwKCAjw6qqDBhB-EiwACBs6xysY67i2kDCHZVZaPNphmctbW9tXQo2dHefMh6bcu_vWvU1QetKCxRoC-dAQAvD_BwE&hvadid=352626426223&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=9062705&hvnetw=g&hvqmt=b&hvrand=5888050085681582043&hvtargid=kwd-300183211570&hydadcr=3672_1736369&keywords=robert+c+martin+clean+code&qid=1617622187&sr=8-1)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that performs the action you want:

```py
def code_for_hint_button():
    # [...]
```

Call the function in either cases:

```py
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit()
    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==pygame.K_h:
            code_for_hint_button()
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if mouse_x and mouse_y are over hint button:
            code_for_hint_button()
```